# How to change material-ui elements style(color/fill) dynamically while creating them in map function

Tags: css, react-native, material-ui

I am trying to change the style (colors) of elements in list items as they are created from a map function, which provides the rgb-color.
Using classes works, but to get it right dynamically, sofor the data/color provided by the object array is a problem.
The attempts beneath do show e.g. fill="rgb(48, 183, 0)", but the classes which define it's style still override the dynamically added style

```
  <Select
        multiple
        value={filterList[index]}
        renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
        onChange={(event) => {
           filterList[index] = event.target.value;
           onChange(filterList[index], index, column);
        }}   >

       { processStatusColorsArr.map(({ id, name, color} ) =>(
            MenuItem key={id} value={name} style={{ fill: `${color}%`, color: `${color}%` }}  >
               <Checkbox   
                   fill={color}  style={{ fill: `${color}%`, color: `${color}%` }}  />
               <ListItemText primary={name}
                   color= {color}  />

               <IconButton color={color}
                   fill={color}
                   style={{ fill: `${color}%`, color: `${color}%` }}    />

           </MenuItem>
       ))}
 </Select>
```

I have also tried this,

{render_filter_process_status_colors(color)} in place of  '<IconButton ..../>'

where I have (above this)

```
const render_filter_process_status_colors = (value, tableMeta, updateValue) =>  {
if(value === undefined) return;

return (
        <div>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={"square"} style={value} size={"lg"} fixedWidth/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but no luck.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using  the function

```
{render_filter_process_status_colors(color)}
```

which is defined as

```
const render_filter_process_status_colors = (value, tableMeta, updateValue) =>  {
if(value === undefined) return;
const iconColor = {color: value}
return (
        <div>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={"square"} style={iconColor} size={"lg"} fixedWidth/>
        </div>
); }
```

I get the icon with the color from my array of rgb colors.